# How can I show just the message for an annotated tag?

Tags: git, git-tag

There seem to be ways in git to show the message of an annotated tag as well as the commit detail and other stuff `git show the_tag`, or the name and the detail `git tag -l -n100 the_tag`.

But what command shows the message/body and absolutely nothing else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the convenience commands are doing too much, go for the core :-)

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/$tagname --format='%(contents)'
```

<sup>[for-each-ref docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref)</sup>

Comment: That `$tagname` isn't literal, replace it with `the_tag`.  f-e-r produces no output when it finds no refs matching the pattern arguments

Answer (score 3):

And you can use `git show`, which is a porcelain command with auto-completion:

```bash
git show -s --format='' <tag>
```

Here `-s` is equivalent to `--no-patch`, which suppresses the diff output. And with the empty format string (`--format=''`), nothing about the commit is printed, either.

#### Example

```
$ git show -s --format='' v2.40.0
tag v2.40.0
Tagger: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
 
Git 2.40
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
...
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Comment: Add `--color` flag to get colorized output. Makes it easy to read on the terminal. 

`git show -s --color --format='' <tag>`